# How to post request to Flask using vue?

Tags: python, vue.js, flask

I want to `post` data from Vue to flask

If I don't use parameter `data: {}`，it's no problem.

[image]

If I use, error occurs

[image]

and this is the server (HTTP Status Code is 200)

[image]

Why is this happening? What should I do?

code：

---

Home.vue

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  created() {   
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      axios({
        baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5001',
        url: '/recData',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
          firstName: 'Fred',
          lastName: 'Flintstone'
        }
      }).then(res=>{
              console.log(res);
      }).catch(err=>{
          console.log(err);
      })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

fls_2.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/recData',methods=['GET','POST'])
def recData():
    if request.method=='POST':
        return '--- post ---'
    if request.method=='GET':
        return '--- get ---'

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=5001, debug=True)
```

Comment: Did you specify a proxy in `vue.config.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a proxy in `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
 devServer: {
  proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:5001',
 }
}
```

there is a good article about it in this link: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3

Comment: I tried but it's doesn't work 
`module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/webPage/'
    : '/',
    devServer: {
      proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:5001',
      }
}
`  have same error message, in vue-cli3

Comment: Dear @pcymichael, I think you cant read `process.env.NODE_ENV`! try to log it in the browser console and check if it logged or not. if not, you can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `vue.config.js` and restart your server after the configuration change.

```
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        target: "http://localhost:5001",
        ws: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: 'debug'
      }
    }
```

Use this in your component.

```
    let url = "/recData";
    let payload = {
       firstName: "Fred", 
       lastName: "Flintstone"
    }
    axios.post(url, payload)
       .then(res=>{
          console.log(res);
       })
       .catch(err=>{
          console.log(err);
       });
```

I hope it works and I was able to help you.